# TypeScript Type for HTML Element Tag

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

I am working on a TypeScript + React project. For a component, I want to use the polymorphic `as` prop. However, I want to restrict it to HTML tags so it will not accept ReactNodes or JSX Elements. But I do not know which type I can use to achieve this.

```
<Foo as="section">...</Foo> ✅
<Foo as={SomeOtherComponent}>...</Foo> ❌
```

I have tried using React.ElementType but that still looks to accept other components.

```
interface Foo {
  as?: React.ElementType
}
```

Which type could I use to accept only HTML tags but not other elements or nodes?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could accept only a string, not a function:

```typescript
interface Foo {
    as?: string;
}
```

Or you could more specifically accept only known HTML tag names using a string literal union; you don't have to write out the names yourself, you can get them from `HTMLElementTagNameMap` in `lib.dom.d.ts`:

```typescript
interface Foo {
    as?: keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap; // This is "a" | "abbr" | "address" ...
}
```

Comment: Dumb question, but where I do import 'HTMLElementTagNameMap' from? I'm getting undefined and it doesn't seem to be part of React or JSX. I am getting and undefined error when using it. But that looks to be the thing I want though.

Comment: @Yuschick - Not a dumb question. :-) You don't need to import it, but you do need to tell TypeScript you're using it in the `"lib"` setting in `tsconfig.json`. For example: `"lib": [ "dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext" ]`.